# Test/Demo Java RCE deserializatrion

Tags: java, security, openshift, netcat

I am trying to set up a lab to demonstrate the Java deserialization remote code execution bug within an Openshift managed container.

I can get the code to run some arbitrary code, but I would like to get a reverse shell. I can run netcat to listen locally and from a shell in the container with -e and all works fine, but when I try to exploit my vulnerability it exists the netcat locally as soon as the connection is established.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide some code? We're developers here. We like code a lot.